# Spring @ContextHierarchy with custom initializer using addActiveProfile gives NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring

We are using @ContextHierarchy in our tests to enable context caching but allow some texts to customise the context. I have a problem that one test needs to activate a specific Spring profile which activates a bean which is injected back into the test.

I have a feeling this is not possible but am looking for confirmation. Logically the parent context has already been initialised, so am willing to believe Spring will have a problem re-wiring the parent context based on a profile being activated in a test that is essentially just adding a child context through @ContextHierarchy. But I couldn't find anyone describing this problem after some googling.

The base test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextHierarchy(
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = BaseConfig.class, initializers =  TestContextInitialiser.class)
)
public abstract class BaseTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
...
}
```

The concrete test class looks like this:

```
@ContextHierarchy(
    @ContextConfiguration(initializers = NotificationTest.CustomInitializer.class)
)
public class NotificationTest extends BaseTest {
    @Autowired
    private EventsConfig eventsConfig; // bean that needs to be activated via profile

    ...

    public static class CustomInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().addActiveProfile("EVENTS_ENABLED");
        }
    }
}
```

The EventsConfig class uses @Profile...

```
@Component
@Profile("EVENTS_ENABLED")
public class EventsConfig {
    ...
}
```

And the error from Spring:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [xxx.EventsConfig] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I would expect that Spring would at least warn/error in this situation and explain that the parent context cannot be modified with new profiles.

Any input/guidance appreciated. Is this or something similar possible? It will be a pain to have to refactor this test to avoid use of the base class.

Thanks